# In Short Job First (SJF) scheduling algorithm does IO bound jobs get priority over CPU bound jobs?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler, scheduling

Recently I came across the statement that

> In SJF IO bound jobs get priority over CPU bound jobs.

I found this statement in page 4 of [this slide](http://lass.cs.umass.edu/%7Eshenoy/courses/fall12/lectures/Lec05.pdf) and also in page 3 of [this slide](http://lass.cs.umass.edu/%7Eshenoy/courses/fall12/lectures/notes/Lec05_notes.pdf). I decide to attach the corresponding pictures below, if in case the link breaks in the future.

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

But I am having difficulty to understand the above and it seems rather counter intuitive to me. My argument is as follows:

I assume a CPU bound  process is one which uses has higher `CPU burst:(CPU Burst+IO Burst)` and I assume a process as IO bound which has higher `IO Burst:(CPU Burst+IO Burst)`. I assumed it from the knowledge I have received after reading the textbook "Operating Concepts" by *Galvin et. al* and the excerpt is below:

> An **I/O-bound process** is one that spends more of its time doing I/O than it spends doing computations. A **CPU-bound process**, in contrast, generates I/O requests infrequently, using more of its time doing computations.

Which I guess agrees with what the professor says [here](https://youtu.be/tfvOSqmg0vk?t=2602).

Based on this I came up with the following examples:

Suppose I have two jobs

```
JOB 1: CPU BURST = 10 units; IO BURST =100 units
JOB 2: CPU BURST= 100 units; IO BURST=10 units...
```

SJF shall schedule JOB1 first which is IO Bound...
———————————————————————————

suppose I have two other jobs

```
JOB 3: CPU BURST = 10 units; IO BURST =1 units
JOB 4: CPU BURST= 100 units; IO BURST=200 units...
```

SJF shall schedule JOB3 first which is CPU bound...

---

From the above example I do not find any such correlation that SJF gives priority to IO bound jobs.